# Scalable chatroom using (playframework akka and websocket)

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka, scalability

I've been asked to build a chatroom that **scale** using Play (java), Akka and websocket.

Play provide a [sample](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/tree/2.2.x/samples/java/websocket-chat) that do what I wanted and it works perfectly.

Now I need to deal with the scaling issue. I'm not familiar with play and scaling problematics so I'm having a hard time to find a solution that will scale. Or at least prove that the sample will scale (which I doubt).
I know that actor system offers good performance but how can I be sure that it will scale ?

Does anyone of you would be able to explain me/provide me links that explain how to build such application that will really scale ? What would be the architecture ?

I've found a an [example](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/play-java-websockets-advanced) on Heroku but i'd like alternatives to heroku. Maybe akka.cluster is one ?

Thank you,

Comment: You can try my example : https://github.com/Yurii-Buhryn/play-akka-cluster-websocket-chat This this sample of integration a play framework 2 app (java) with akka cluster. It's provide a possibility to add new play node for scale system. when a new node added all nodes in the cluster share chat messages, no matter which node receives the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not exactly the technology stack you are looking for, [scalable-chat](https://github.com/ezoerner/scalable-chat) is a Scala project that uses [akka cluster](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.7/common/cluster.html) to scale chatrooms on the back end. Instead of Play on the front end it uses a ScalaFX client, but the principle and architecture is the same.

The communication layer uses akka-io with akka-stream, and the plan is to use akka-http with websockets once that becomes available.

Unfortunately the example doesn't yet show scaling with multiple chatrooms, but does with multiple users and using akka-persistence for chat history with a cluster-aware router. Another plan for this project is to use [cluster sharding](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3-M2/contrib/cluster-sharding.html) for persistent user and chatroom actors.

Although this example doesn't give you a complete solution, perhaps it can provide some inspiration for building a scalable chatroom backend using Akka Cluster.